# Got VPN setup to AWS EC2, how to setup RDP access?

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, openvpn, rdp

I setup OpenVPN on a AWS EC2 windows server and got my client pc to VPN successfully to the EC2 instance. How can I setup and allow RDP access? I want to allow access only when I VPN.

I tried connecting to the VPN and then tried RDP to the private IP of the EC2 instance but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked security group of your RDP server? There needs to be a rule to allow port 3389 from NAT instance (by IP or by security group).